# Selenide GRID - how to configure

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-grid, selenide

I'm trying to run GRID using Selenide but I'm getting an error. I have a hub with two nodes - one with firefox and second with chrom. I also use this configuration

```
    Configuration.browser = "chrome";
    Configuration.remote="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";
    Configuration.baseUrl = "http://typujwynik.cba.pl/index.php?cmd=mypreds";
```

Unfortunatelly Im getting:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:32:19.891Z'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-1OF5RPN0', ip: '192.168.1.18', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Command duration or timeout: 74 milliseconds
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
    at ...
```

Can anyone advice why it doesn't work?
I Selenide FAQs says that it is suffitient to add `Configuration.remote="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";`

http://selenide.org/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

via Configuration like so:

`Configuration.remote="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";`

or via maven like so:

`-Dremote="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"`

Make sure the browser is matching to your node, case sensitivity is likely a factor, as `selenide.browser` is `Chrome` and your node is likely `chrome`